# React universal app (server side rendering) not showing retrieved data in web browser's view page source, what i am doing wrong?

Tags: reactjs

I have created a simple react universal app.
I am using nodejs express as backend server,
on the react component, in the componentDidMount function, I make a get request to a api to retrieve a list of items to render on the react component.
this works fine.
however , to verify ,  i click on the browser's  view page source, to view the page source,
i see that the react component is rendered on the server, BUT the data is not PRESENT on the page source.
my question is what am i doing wrong, i expect to see the page and data retrieved from the get request in the page source .
how do i ensure that the promise is resolved before rendering the view?

my code is below.

REACT COMPONENT

```
import React from 'react';
import Listing from '../../shared/listing.component.jsx';
import axios from 'axios';
import Auto from '../item/auto-list-item.component.jsx';
export default class AutosList extends React.Component{

    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state={
            data:[]
        }
    }

     componentDidMount () {
         let data=axios.get('http://localhost:5000/autos')
         data.then((res)=>{

             this.setState({
                   data:res.data
             });
         })
     }
      render(){
          return(
              <div>
                  <header>
                      <h1>Autos page</h1>
                  </header>
                  <div>
                     {
                       this.state.data.map((item,i)=><Auto key={i} auto={item}/>)
                     }
                  </div>
              </div>
          );
      }

}
```

--REACT ROUTER---

```
import React from 'react';
import { Router, browserHistory } from 'react-router';
import routes from './routes.jsx';
export default class AppRoutes extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return ( 
            <Router history={browserHistory} routes={routes}/>
        );
    }

}
```

//ROURES

```
const routes=(
                <Route path="/" component={App}>
                  <IndexRoute component={Home}/>
                  <Route path="home" component={Home}/>
                  <Route path="autos" component={Autos}/>
                  <Route path="auto/:id" component={AutoDetails} />
                </Route>  
);

export default routes;
```

--EXPRESS ROUTE---

```
import Express from 'express';
import path from 'path'
import React from 'react';
import { renderToString } from 'react-dom/server';
import { match, RouterContext } from 'react-router';
import routes from './components/routing/routes.jsx';

const app = new Express();
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.use(Express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));

app.get("*", function(req, res) {
            match({ routes, location: req.url }, function(err, redirectLocation, renderProps) {
                    if (err) {
                        return res.status(500).send(err.message);
                    }
                    //if there is a redirection, pass it back to express to handle
                    if (redirectLocation) {
                        return res.redirectLocation(302, redirectLocation.pathname + redirectLocation.search);
                    }

                    //if we have render props, render routes
                    if (renderProps) {
                        let html = renderToString( < RouterContext {...renderProps }
                            />);

                            return res.render("index", { html });
                        }
                        return res.status(404).send("not Found");
                    });
            });


        const PORT = process.env.PORT || 9000;

        app.listen(PORT, error => {
            if (error) {
                return console.error(error);
            }
            console.log(`Express server listening on port ${PORT} localhost`);
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you're retrieving the data for props within `Component` an `axios.get`in instead of doing what I've seen done often which is populate the window object with `<script dangerouslySetInnerHTML={ { __html: 'window.PROPS=' + JSON.stringify(custom) } }/>` placed as a prop within your parent rendering component .

---

To my knowledge , that is what causes the source code in your inspector to have all of the data included (typically). Right now you are just serving it as `JSON` through a `get` call to your `REST` API, thus maintaining the isomorphism required to render without an error, But completely bypassing the need for the data to be stored in the `window` , thus - there are no props in the inspection code.

---

`(Continued 2/5/2017 from 2/4/2017)`

It should look something like ..

`(Example Code)`

This is your code with just the script tag inserted. The only difference between my insertion and this one is that this is done inside of `<body></body>` while this is done in a div. let me know if it works out.

As you can see, under the assumption that when the jsx goes to render, all state will have been set so I deconstruct using `const { data } = this.state` and then `dangerouslySetInnerHtml`

```
export default class AutosList extends React.Component {

    constructor () {
        super();
        this.state = {
            data: []
        }
    }

    componentWillMount () {
        let data = axios.get('http://localhost:5000/autos')
        //
        data.then((res) => {
            this.setState({
                data: res.data
            });
        })
    }

    render () {
        const { data } = this.state // => const data = this.state.data
        return (
            <div>
                <header>
                    <h1>Autos page</h1>
                </header>
                <div>
                    {
                        this.state.data.map((item, i) => <Auto key={i} auto={item}/>)
                    }
                </div>
                <script dangerouslySetInnerHTML={ { __html: 'window.PROPS=' + JSON.stringify(data) } }/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: its not an error , the page is rendered on the UI correctly, and the retrieved data is displayed, but when i click on view page souce on chrome i dont see the data in the page source  . it is a universal application,

Comment: I have done a decent amount of working with react and have made some minimalist boilerplates that could possibly help. My Server side one even shows you how to get immutablejs working and integrated [react-redux-immutable-serverside-rendering](https://github.com/CodeBlackwell/server-side-Immutable-react-redux) .

Comment: Thanks for the boiler plate, I am currently taking a look at redux from the basics, I will refactor the project to use redux once I have some hands on, the link you provided will be of help, for now, could you give some code sample of setting the props by populating the window object in dangerouslysetinnerhtml, i.e both client and server? thanks

Answer (score 0):

When rendering server side, `componentDidMount` won't be called. Only `componentWillMount` is called with server side rendering.

Here: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillmount

> componentWillMount() is invoked immediately before mounting occurs. It
>   is called before render(), therefore setting state in this method will
>   not trigger a re-rendering. Avoid introducing any side-effects or
>   subscriptions in this method.
>
> This is the only lifecycle hook called on server rendering. Generally,
>   we recommend using the constructor() instead.

**EDIT**
On top of that, your data fetching call is an asynchronous function: it takes some time for the request to be sent and return with results. With SSR however, your code is executed synchronously, meaning it never waits for data to be ready.

This is one of the tricks of SSR when data fetching is involved (that is usually overlooked in boilerplates), and you can quickly check it by adding some `console.log` after your `axios` call comes, and see if you see it one the server. I bet you don't.

For a quick hack to verify, you could simply add a `setTimeout` on your server code with 500ms delay to give time to your API to respond, and then send the full rendered app to the client.

Comment: Thanks for the reply charley, so if i am correct, you mean i should trigger setstate inside of ComponentWillMOunt rather than componentDidMOunt? and could you provide a direction on how i trigger componentWillMOunt from server, express, and how i pass data to the right component from server? thanks